# How to invoke dart function from android service after appication is closed?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification

i want to implement a push notification with socket io. when a message or notification is received i want to invoke corresponding flutter function. currently i implemented android service but i don't know how to communicate with flutter from service when application is closed. I have already looked into FCM github code but it is confusing

Comment: pls add more detail possible and the code you've done so far

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/BasicMessageChannel-class.html